# Trying to run a ForEach block, no output files even though "successful"

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

Have an array of values to run through an API however when I run it through the ForEach block for each item in the array, the pipeline says it is successful however looking at the output, there is nothing there.

This is the overall pipeline [image: overall pipeline].

This is the integration dataset that I am using [image: here]. I've made the container (correctly I hope) and within that container I want to store it in the testfolder, and to name each file according to the item number followed by ".csv".

I've triggered the pipeline and it runs successfully however there is no output in the data lake. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one of the following expressions in **filename**.

First, give **file path** correctly as below in dataset.

[image]

Next, add below in **file name** field in the sink settings.

```
file@{item()}.csv
```

Or

```
@concat('file',item(),'.csv')
```

[image]

Output:

[image]

and

[image]